# How can I stop 2 outlets being controlled by a switch?

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle

I have two outlets where the the lower half is controlled by a wall switch and the upper half is always on. I’d like to remove the switch and have the upper and lower parts of the outlets always live.

This is the switch wiring has red, black, and ground wires:
[image: switch wiring]

One of the outlets has two white wires to the top and bottom screen, two red wires to the bottom screw, two black wires to the top screw, and a ground wire:
[image: outlet with lots of wires]

The other outlet has one white wire, one red white to the bottom screw, one black wire to the top screw, and a ground wire:
[image: outlet with a few wires]

What changes should I make to have both outlets always live?

Comment: I'm happy with that. I can replace it with a blank plate or something.

Comment: Nope, just a single switch and two receptacles.

Comment: Keep in mind that code *requires* most rooms to have either a switched light or a light that is always on. Builders are cheap so they use the same duplex receptacle that satisfies "1 receptacle every 12 feet" for "switched receptacle to plug in a light". End result though is that you either need to rewire the switch to a permanent light fixture (that's what I had done in my house when I moved in many years ago") or have some light that is always on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to disconnect the red and black wire from the switch and wire nut them together. Use a blank cover to cover the switch box. This allows you to go back to switched outlets in the future if you want. Make sure there will still be a light controlled by a switch by the door.

You can get more involved and disconnect the red wire from the switch and outlets. Get some new outlets and hook them up to the black wire and the white wire, and ground. The old outlets have tabs broken on the side with the brass screws that allow the outlet to be switched. Rather that try to use jumpers to "replace" the tabs, new outlets are advised. Cap the red wire at all locations. A light controlled by a switch by the door is still requires.

Comment: Would I keep both black and white wires on the first outlet?
I have a fan light on a switch at the door so that should cover the requirement.

Comment: @acyphus  Yes, wire them the same, just black, white and ground.  Black wires on brass screws and white wires on silver screws.